# Method Not Allowed when patching registration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Recently some registrations of commands expired so I am trying to patch their "expires" attribute. However, I receive a `405 method not allowed` message error.

Retrieving info about the registration:

```
curl -X GET \
http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations/5d3ff3e2ab1e270d7775a7bf \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

```
{
    "id": "5d3ff3e2ab1e270d7775a7bf",
    "expires": "2019-08-29T07:38:10.00Z",
    "dataProvided": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:ActuatorScreenshot:001",
                "type": "Actuator"
            }
        ],
        "attrs": [
            "Screen"
        ]
    },
    "provider": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://localhost:4041"
        },
        "supportedForwardingMode": "all",
        "legacyForwarding": true
    },
    "status": "active"
}
```

I attempted following the example from http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/:

```
curl -X PATCH \
  http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations/5d3ff3e2ab1e270d7775a7bf \
  -d '{
    "expires":"2040-10-04T00:00:00"
}'
```

But as I said I got the error message:
`405 Method Not Allowed`

Feel free to ask for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation to modify registrations has not been yet implemented in Orion 2.2.0 (last version in the moment of writing this). As mentioned in [Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/ngsiv2_implementation_notes/index.html#registrations):

> Orion implements registration management as described in the NGSIv2
>   specification, except for the following aspects:
>
> - List item `PATCH /v2/registration/<id>` is not implemented. Thus, registrations cannot be updated directly. I.e., updates must be done
>     deleting and re-creating the registration. Please see [this
>     issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3007) about
>     this.

However, the workaround is pretty simple: delete the old registration and create a new one with the modified parameters.